# Failed to allocate managed memory in Dynamics CRM using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, contacts

I've `1,072,369` contact records in Dynamics CRM. I needed to retrieve them and then manipulate. Now, while retrieving I faced following exception

**Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 1073741824 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low.**

I increased its time span to 10 minutes but no luck.

I am seeking your kind advise/help to resolve it. Following is my code snippet.

```
ColumnSet col = new ColumnSet();
col.AddColumns("new_name", "accountid", "contactid");

                //get Related Record
                QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression
                {
                    EntityName = entity,
                    ColumnSet = col,
                    Criteria = new FilterExpression
                    {
                        Conditions = { 
                        new ConditionExpression("accountid",ConditionOperator.NotNull),
                        new ConditionExpression("statecode",ConditionOperator.Equal,0)
                    }
                    }
                };

                EntityCollection ec = sp.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `1,072,369`, so i suggest you retrieve these records in batches. You can try the following piece of code to try, if it helps retrieve records.

```
            QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = entity,
                ColumnSet = col,
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    Conditions = { 
                    new ConditionExpression("accountid",ConditionOperator.NotNull),
                    new ConditionExpression("statecode",ConditionOperator.Equal,0)
                }
                }
            };

            qe.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();
            qe.PageInfo.PagingCookie = null;
            qe.PageInfo.PageNumber = 1;
            qe.PageInfo.Count = 500;

while (true)
            {
                EntityCollection results= sp.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
                if (results.Entities != null)
                {

                }

                // Check for more records, if it returns true.
                if (results.MoreRecords)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n****************\nPage number {0}\n****************", pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine("#\tAccount Name\t\tEmail Address");

                    // Increment the page number to retrieve the next page.
                    pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber++;

                    // Set the paging cookie to the paging cookie returned from current results.
                    pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = results.PagingCookie;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If no more records are in the result nodes, exit the loop.
                    break;
                }
            }
```

**Refer here for more details:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327917.aspx[Page large result sets with QueryExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327917.aspx)

[PAGING QUERIES IN DYNAMICS CRM 2011](https://roscode.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/paging-queries-in-dynamics-crm-2011/)